# Using JS to create number using regex still creating repeated digits

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex, wherein no digits must repeat:

```
^(?!.*(.).*\1)\d{3}$
```

I'm using the [Fent JS](http://fent.github.io/randexp.js/) library to test creation of a 3 digit number but so far it still produces numbers that have repeated digits, e.g. 333, 444, 555, 800, 900, 112, etc. I want all three digits to be unique.

What's missing in my regex?

Comment: Your expression seems to work fine, see [here](https://regex101.com/r/cktowP/1).

Comment: @UnbearableLightness, I think I have worded my question badly. But I'm trying to make numbers using the library linked above and when I use the expression, it still makes numbers with repeated digits.

Comment: Seems to be a problem with that website then, I tried using an alternative expression like `^(\d)((?!\1)\d)(?!\1|\2)\d$` which you can try [here](https://regex101.com/r/cktowP/2) and still does not work properly on Fent JS.

Comment: Perhaps you can submit an issue on the Github page.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness thanks! No answer from you?

Comment: What do you mean? :)

Comment: I meant you didn't write an answer below

Comment: Ah, right, I have submitted an answer now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression correctly matches three unique digits, as you can see [here](https://regex101.com/r/cktowP/1).

An alternative expression could be:

```
^(\d)((?!\1)\d)(?!\1|\2)\d$
```

- `^` Assert position beginning of line.
- `((?!\1)\d)` Capturing group. Negative lookahead to assert that what follows is not what was captured in group one, then match a digit.
- `(?!\1|\2)\d` Negative lookahead to assert that what follows is not what was captured in group one or two, then match a digit.
- `$` Assert position end of line.

You can test this second regex live [here](https://regex101.com/r/cktowP/2).

Having tested both expressions on the resource you provided [here](http://fent.github.io/randexp.js/), I would conclude that it is indeed an issue with the Fent JS. I would suggest you submit an issue in the Github page [here](https://github.com/fent/randexp.js).

Answer (score -1):

There may be an issue with 'Fent JS' lib itself. Your regex works fine. You could try this instead. Generate random 3 digit number in javascript using `Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000))` and then test your regex (`^(?!.*(.).*\1)\d{3}$`) against it to see if it matches and then use the matched number.

Comment: I can't downvote even if I wanted to :)...not enough reputation yet